# Stackoverflow Exception in Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, sudoku, stack-overflow

Today I wanted to write a program that solves a sudoku.
When my approach didn't quite work I resorted to a solution found here: http://www.heimetli.ch/ffh/simplifiedsudoku.html

But for some reason, I keep getting a StackOverflow Exception.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sudoku_Solver
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainClass _mainClass = new MainClass();

        _mainClass.printSudoku();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    private const int FieldsVertical = 3, FieldsHorizontal = 3;
    private const int RowsInField = 3, ColumnsInField = 3;

    Thread _sudokuSolverThread;

    private int[,] Sudoko = new int[(FieldsVertical * ColumnsInField), (FieldsHorizontal * RowsInField)]{
        { 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        { 7, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 0, 9, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0},
        { 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 9},
        { 0, 9, 4, 2, 0, 6, 8, 1, 0},
        { 6, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
        { 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0},
        { 0, 3, 0, 4, 6, 0, 7, 0, 2},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 3},
    };

    public MainClass(){ }

    private void startSudokuSolver()
    {
        solveSudoku(0, 0);
    }

    private bool solveSudoku(int row, int col)
    {
        if (Sudoko[row, col] != 0)
        {
            return next(row, col++);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsInField * RowsInField; i++)
            {
                if (checkColumn(i, row) && checkField(i, row, col) && checkRow(i, col))
                {
                    Sudoko[row, col] = i;

                    //Thread.Sleep(10);

                    return next(row, col++);
                }
            }
            Sudoko[row, col] = 0;

            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool next(int row, int col)
    {
        if (row == 9)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (col == 9)
            {
                return solveSudoku(row++, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                return solveSudoku(row, col);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printSudoku()
    {
        startSudokuSolver();

        for (int i = 0; i < Sudoko.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Sudoko.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                Console.Write(Sudoko[i, x] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    private bool checkRow(int number, int col)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < FieldsVertical * RowsInField; row++)
        {
            if (Sudoko[row, col] == number)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool checkColumn(int number, int row)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < FieldsHorizontal * ColumnsInField; column++)
        {
            if (Sudoko[row, column] == number)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    int _currentFieldRow;
    int _currentFieldColumn;

    private bool checkField(int number, int row, int col)
    {
        _currentFieldRow = (row / RowsInField) * RowsInField;
        _currentFieldColumn = (col / ColumnsInField) * ColumnsInField;

        for (int a = _currentFieldRow; a < _currentFieldRow + RowsInField; a++)
        {
            for (int b = _currentFieldColumn; b < _currentFieldColumn + ColumnsInField; b++)
            {
                if (Sudoko[a, b] == number)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the stack trace on the exception?  That should give you an idea of what's going on.  Additionally consider debugging the code to see where the program is failing to function as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E.g. here

```
            return solveSudoku(row++, 0);
```

the original value of `row` is passed to the function `solveSudoku` (and after that `row` is incremented). Change it to `row + 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is unfortunately always the small things.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the StackOverflowException is in the next() method. Change

```
return solveSudoku(row, col);
```

to

```
return solveSudoku(row, ++col);
```

This does at least solve the StackOverflowException. Anyway, you need to enhance the algorithm further as it does not solve the complete Sudoku yet.